# how can I extract a Version number from a website with curl and grep / sed?

Tags: curl, grep, sed, awk

I want to get the latets version number from this website:
https://www.mailpiler.org/wiki/download

so I do a curl to get the content and then just use a pipe to search for the string using grep
`curl https://www.mailpiler.org/wiki/download | grep piler-`

but this way I get the whole line like this:
`<a href="https://bitbucket.org/jsuto/piler/downloads/piler-1.3.12.tar.gz" class="urlextern" title="https://bitbucket.org/jsuto/piler/downloads/piler-1.3.12.tar.gz" rel="ugc nofollow">piler-1.3.12</a> (~3.3 <abbr title="Megabyte">MB</abbr>), 2022.05.28.`

now.. how can I remove everythign but the version number (1.3.12)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk you can use command like this:

```
curl -k -s  https://www.mailpiler.org/wiki/download |awk -F'[-".]' '/piler-/ {OFS=".";print $4,$5,$6}'
```

you do not need `grep` because `awk` can act on similar way.